# My Powershell showing this location issue The 'Set-Location' command was found in the module .but the module could not be loaded

Tags: node.js, powershell, developer-tools

The 'Set-Location' command was found in the module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Management', but the module could not be
loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Management'.

- CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-Location:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule

Comment: Patch Tuesday was 2 days ago, have you perhaps installed patches and not rebooted?

Comment: then how I can get it back

Comment: Hey, I was just suggesting that you reboot your machine and check to make sure that didn't resolve the issue. For `Set-Location` to be missing seems improbable.

Comment: But it stills showing the same issue after rebooting .

Comment: This is one of the rare times I'd say a PowerShell question is *not* on topic for Stack Overflow. If the *built-in* modules aren't loading this qualifies as a systems issue (and you have bigger problems than APIs). I recommend asking about this on [su] and researching how to perform a repair installation on PowerShell. But considering Windows PowerShell is a major core component of Windows, you might need a repair installation.

Comment: To finish my cutoff comment above; you might need a repair installation of Windows itself